# Uploading Amazon Inventory UTF 8 Encoding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, inventory, amazon-product-api, uploading

I am trying to upload my english inventory to various european amazon sites. The issue I am having is that the accents found in certain different languages are not displaying correctly when an "inventory file" is uploaded to amazon. The inventory file is a tab delimited text file.

current setup:

```
$type = 'text/tab-separated-values; charset=utf-8';
header('Content-Type:'.$type);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="inventory-'.$_GET['cc'].'.txt');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($data));
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
```

When the text file is outputted and saved it looks exactly how it should when opened in windows (all the characters are correct) but for some reason amazon doesn't see it as UTF8 and re-encodes it with all of the characters found here:

http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

I have tried adding the BOM to the top of the file but this just results in amazon giving an error. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Don't know whether [this document](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/mwsportal/doc/en_US/bde/MWSFeedsApiReference._V372272532_.pdf) is still valid, but on page 13 it says that a flat file for NA & Europe should be encoded `text/tab-separated-values; charset=iso-8859-1`

Comment: "I have tried adding the BOM" Don't do that. The BOM was only for text editors to show the character set, and it was a terrible idea. It should never be used.

Comment: Please could you use the following code to extract the actual bytes of your text, which will show if they're actually utf-8 or some other character set. $resultInHex = unpack('H*', $result);
$resultInHex = $resultInHex[1];

$resultSeparated = implode(', ', mb_str_split($resultInHex, 2));

echo "in hex: ".$resultSeparated;

Comment: Just tried your tip fvu and it doesn't work, everything looks fine up until it's uploaded so I can't work it out. The inhex value I get is 2

Answer (score 1):

As @fvu pointed out in his comment, Amazon is expecting the `ISO-8859-1` format, not `UTF-8`. That's why you should use PHP's [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) method when writing to your file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after a lot of trying it turns out that the characters needed to be decoded. I opened the text files in excel and they seemed to encode themselves as weird characters like Ã¼ using php utf8_decode turned them back into the correct characters EVEN THOUGH the text file showed them as the right characters... very confusing.

To anyone out there having difficulties with UTF 8 try decoding first.

thanks for your help